# Create snippet and code completion from custom language

Tags: compilation, editor, integration, code-snippets, erp

I work with an ERP, but the tools that it offers are very poor and non-practical, so I want to integrate an external editor and create snippets and code completion for it. It has its own built-in language, any ideas are welcome.

Comment: What ERP? What does the internal language look like? What _specifically_ are you trying to do?

Comment: The ERP is the [Senior](http://www.senior.com.br/), the language looks like Pascal and Algol but translated to portuguese, I am trying to use something like vscode or another editor to make less painful the development on this language.

Comment: So to be clear, you just want a text editor that you can configure to work nicely with this language (i.e. generate snippets of repetitive code, autocomplete keywords, etc.)?

Comment: hm, I wasn't clear enough, sorry, kinda. I want that, and also highlight the code, but I don't want to rewrite all that, because the built-in editor highlight the code, so I known that already has a dictionary or something like, what I don't known is how to extract this and reuse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### option 1: customizing the ERP editor

Integrating snippets and other features into the existing ERP editor would probably be difficult. Assuming it's provided as a web application, you could (in theory) write some Javascript that listens to the text you write into the built-in editor and then modifies it accordingly (blowing up expansions according to snippets you define, autocompleting words, etc.), but this might be brittle if the underlying HTML/Javascript changes, and difficult because you'll have to figure out how to reliably inject your custom Javascript whenever you load the website.

### option 2: customizing your editor of choice for the ERP language

It sounds like the only thing the ERP editor is providing you with is syntax highlighting and maybe keyword autocompletion. If that's it, then in general those things aren't hard to implement in your editor of choice (e.g. for Vim, adding keyword autocompletion is as simple as dumping the keywords into a text file, and syntax highlighting involves defining some regular expressions). The benefit of doing this is that you'll also have access to all of your editor's other pleasantries, like navigation hotkeys, snippet plugins, and more.